# run deSolve multiple times varying a time-varying parameter

Tags: r, ode

I would like to get this code to run repeatedly, creating a single output dataset with a different column variable for each run. Right now, the code works and allows me to insert different events at varying times. However, I would like to be able to change the magnitude of the event,

```
IPT  <- ifelse (t<210, IPT, 0.35*exp(-(t-209)/21))
```

varying 0.35 to 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, etc. I have tried For loops but couldn't get it to work at all. My code is below:

```
library(deSolve)
##Simple parameter list
params <- c(b = 0.477, bs = .4, bsv = 0.1, nets = 0.4767, betah = 0.2, 
        rhos = 179, Bthetas = 0.2, psi = 14,phis = 0.5, gamma =14, 
        thetas = 0.79,piv = 1/19, betav = 0.09122, nu = 0.2085, sigma = 12, 
        muv = 1/19, IPT = 0, IPT2 = 0, IPT3 = 0)
dt      <- seq(0, 5000, 7)
inits      <- c(Ss = 30000, Is = 0, As = 0, Rs = 0,
            Sv = 29999, Ev = 0, Iv = 1)
Nh <- 30000
Nv <- 30000


## Create an SIR function
sir1 <- function(t, x, params) {

with(as.list(c(params, x)), {

IPT  <- ifelse (t<210, IPT, 0.35*exp(-(t-209)/21))

dSs <- -((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss         /Nh                                 + As*(1/rhos)*(1-Bthetas)                                                                         + Rs*(1/psi)
dIs <-  ((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss*(1-phis)/Nh - 1/gamma   * Is                                                            - Is*(IPT + IPT2  + IPT3)
dAs <-  ((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss*(  phis)/Nh + 1/gamma  * Is*(1-thetas) - As*(1/rhos)*(1-Bthetas) - As*(2/rhos)*Bthetas                          - As*(IPT + IPT2 + IPT3)
dRs <-                                                               1/gamma * Is*(  thetas)                           + As*(2/rhos)*Bthetas + Is*(IPT2 +    IPT3+ IPT) + As*(IPT + IPT2 + IPT3) - Rs*(1/psi)  

dSv <- piv*Nv - Sv*betav*b*(nu*(
    ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*As)+
   ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*Is/Nh) - Sv*muv 
dEv <-          Sv*betav*b*(nu*(
  ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*As)+
    ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*Is/Nh)  - Ev*(1/sigma + muv)
dIv <-      Ev*(1/sigma)- Iv*muv


der <- c(dSs, dIs, dAs, dRs,
         dSv, dEv, dIv)
list(der)
 })
 }

out <- as.data.frame(lsoda(inits, dt, sir1, parms = params))

out$prev <- with(out, Is+As/Nh)
```

I would like the final data set to have multiple prev columns, one for each run with different values of the event.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution would be to have the magnitude be a parameter instead of a constant (here I call it `mag`).

```
library(deSolve)
##Simple parameter list
params <- c(b = 0.477, bs = .4, bsv = 0.1, nets = 0.4767, betah = 0.2, 
        rhos = 179, Bthetas = 0.2, psi = 14,phis = 0.5, gamma =14, 
        thetas = 0.79,piv = 1/19, betav = 0.09122, nu = 0.2085, sigma = 12, 
        muv = 1/19, IPT = 0, IPT2 = 0, IPT3 = 0, mag=0.35)
dt      <- seq(0, 5000, 7)
inits      <- c(Ss = 30000, Is = 0, As = 0, Rs = 0,
            Sv = 29999, Ev = 0, Iv = 1)
Nh <- 30000
Nv <- 30000
```

Then we can adjust the `sir1` function to take the `mag` parameter...

```
## Create an SIR function
sir1 <- function(t, x, params) {

with(as.list(c(params, x)), {

IPT  <- ifelse (t<210, IPT, mag*exp(-(t-209)/21))

dSs <- -((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss         /Nh                                 + As*(1/rhos)*(1-Bthetas)                                                                         + Rs*(1/psi)
dIs <-  ((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss*(1-phis)/Nh - 1/gamma   * Is                                                            - Is*(IPT + IPT2  + IPT3)
dAs <-  ((b*bs*(1-nets))+(b*bs*nets*0.78))*betah*Iv*Ss*(  phis)/Nh + 1/gamma  * Is*(1-thetas) - As*(1/rhos)*(1-Bthetas) - As*(2/rhos)*Bthetas                          - As*(IPT + IPT2 + IPT3)
dRs <-                                                               1/gamma * Is*(  thetas)                           + As*(2/rhos)*Bthetas + Is*(IPT2 +    IPT3+ IPT) + As*(IPT + IPT2 + IPT3) - Rs*(1/psi)  

dSv <- piv*Nv - Sv*betav*b*(nu*(
    ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*As)+
   ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*Is/Nh) - Sv*muv 
dEv <-          Sv*betav*b*(nu*(
  ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*As)+
    ((bsv*(1-nets))+(bsv*nets*0.78))*Is/Nh)  - Ev*(1/sigma + muv)
dIv <-      Ev*(1/sigma)- Iv*muv


der <- c(dSs, dIs, dAs, dRs,
         dSv, dEv, dIv)
list(der)
 })
 }
```

... and we can modify the `params` vector in a loop that also runs the model, gets the output, calculates `prev`, and stores it in the `out` data.frame.

```
out <- as.data.frame(lsoda(inits, dt, sir1, parms = params))
magz <- seq(0.2, 0.5, length.out=10)

for(i in 1:length(magz)){
  params['mag'] <- magz[i]
  tmp <- as.data.frame(lsoda(inits, dt, sir1, parms = params))
  nm <- paste('prev', round(params['mag'],2), sep='')
  out[,nm] <- with(tmp, Is+As/Nh)
}
```

There are likely better ways to do what you want to do, but this is a potential solution.